# Visual Studio 2019 C# Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) - NO View Designer or View Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I checked out a **C# Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)** from GIT and was looking around and making some modifications to the code and the form.  At some point the next day I no longer have any *View Designer* or *View Source* in the *View* menu or when right-clicking the file in Solution Explorer.  Also, double-clicking the file just brings up code view.

- It successfully Builds, Executes, displays the form and functions correctly.

I can't find an option under *File* > *New File* (only Web Form) or anywhere else to add a new form and Solution Explorer shows:

[image]

I have done quit a bit of searching and everything seems to point to using **.NET Core** (which doesn't support Form Designer, without possibly an external package) instead of **.NET Framework** which is not my case.

If I create a new **C# Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)** I do have Form Designer and the ability to view code and form.

Is this a setting in the Project/Solution or in the IDE?  How can I get Form Designer back?  I'm not sure where to look to prove in the question that it is .NET Framework and not .NET Core, but forms were working yesterday.

Comment: What if you add a form to that broken project.  Same issue?  What kind of icons are you getting in your solution tree for those files?

Comment: @LarsTech Edited, thanks!  I don't see where I can add a form.

Comment: Right mouse clicking PingServers folder should give you an option to add a new windows form.  Does that Form1.cs file have any attributes above the class name when you look at the code?

Comment: @LarsTech Only New File, New Item, New Folder and searching in New Item for form only shows Web Form.  Code https://pastebin.com/pyTvEuA4

Comment: Click on the toolbar in your image to switch views from Folder View to Solution View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the view of your project got switched to Folder View.

Click on the Toolbar in the Solution Explorer and switch the view to Solution View.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is this just quirky behavior or something that most users know or is documented?

Comment: @AbraCadaver I don't know if this is Visual Studio 2019 behavior or prior versions, too, but I came across this issue recently when checking out projects from our GitHub account at work.  Once I noticed that "Folder View" in your image, it stirred my brain.